# $(document).ready() clarification

Tags: jquery

I have an aspx page  with 5 user controls. I have `$(document).ready()` in each of these user controls and then one in the main aspx page.

Is this the right approach or I should consider of side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally fine unless you need to run them in a specific order.

Shortcut (works the same way):

```
$(function() {

});
```

Comment: I thank you all. But can accept only one as an answer. But all of the answers are correct. So cheers guys.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine, you just cannot guarantee the order in which they functions will be fired.

Being as that reducing the amount of `$(document).ready()` calls is subjective to the code itself, whether or not it is the correct approach for you to take is hard to say without seeing the code/design.

Answer (score 1):

If the controls are independent of each-other and independent of the page, **YES it is OK** to run `$(document).ready()` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Either combine them or don't, there are no side-effects just a little extra script running.  Whichever is easier to manage is ok, if you have more than a few controls I'd *really* look at combining the output somehow.